# Writting text above textview not inside it in android

Tags: android, textview, dialog

I have a textview, created inside a shape. I want to write text above this text view not inside it. !

I have added image for it. The outer rectangle displayed is a dialog box and inner rectangle is textview.  : https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLUgM.png

My xml looks like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="top"
android:background="@drawable/mydialogbox"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_name"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
/>
```

Now I want to write text above this inner rectangle and inside outer rectangle which is a dilog box.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You will have to add other `TextView` dynamically if you don't want to add it in the xml file.

And then set the text to newly added `TextView`. But the `TextView` must be there to hold text

Answer (score 0):

use two textview one for shape and other one for text.